# InvalidPipeArgument: ',subsection , subsection ' for pipe 'AsyncPipe' Stack trace:

Tags: firebase, angularfire

```
 this.items = this.itemsRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, 
                          detail:   c.payload.val().detail, 
                          tittle: c.payload.val().name , 
                          sub: c.payload.val().sub
}));
```

Outer loop is working find but inner loop shows error
Inner loop

```
 <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngFor="let sub of item.sub | async">
       <button mat-menu-item>
         <mat-icon>dialpad</mat-icon>
         <span>loop</span>
      </button>
    </mat-menu>
```

firebase structure

```
exam

    1

       detail: DETAIL

       image: IMAGE

       name: NAME

         sub-

              1: subsection 
              2: sunsection 

    2

       detail: DETAIL

       image: IMAGE

        name: NAME

            sub-

                 1: subsection

                 2: subsection

                 3:subsection

                 4: subsection
```

every thing in "sub: c.payload.val().sub" subsection come in a single line instant of list i need sub-section in list so that i can iterate through loop

Comment: If you provide a plunkr I will fix it.

Comment: thanks you but i had already fixed it